# "Missing template" when omitting file extensions (.html.twig) or underscore

Tags: templating, phpstorm

I'd like to be able to only have to refer to a file by it's name, just like it works in JS (e.g. `import './js/scripts'`) and SCSS (e.g. `@import './variables'`), without the need for file extensions or underscores.

However, when I try that in Twig, then first of all CraftCMS doesn't like me omitting the "_" when the file starts with one (and the IDE for that matter), and when I omit the file extension, then PhpStorm simply doesn't like it, but CraftCMS can work with it. For everything to look and work smoothly, I need to write the file name as is.

[image]

I'm currently on PhpStorm 2021.3.2 and following are my Symfony and Twig settings

[image]

[image]

Did I forget to change something, or is that just how it is right now?

Comment: me too! After switching to PHPStorm I'm now resigned to putting .twig after everything, and getting colleagues to do the same :-( I suspect this is more a question for JetBrains though as there's not really anything Craft can do about this.

Comment: Manuele what theme are you using?

Comment: @a-am If i remember right, i was using "Material Theme UI" with "Atom Material Icons" at the time, but since I'm a weeb, I've already switched to "Doki Theme". The Material Theme comes with a lot of UI customizations that still seem to apply when using other themes, so I still have it anyways (e.g. to condense everything, i hate the big spaces).